# How can I print the output of the ghostscript txtwrite device?

Tags: generics, printing, driver, ghostscript

My problem is that I want to print the same document on two different printers at the same time. One printer has a Postscript Lexmark printer driver (model T652) and the other one has a generic/text only driver (let's call it the "B" printer). I have been looking for a solution for a while. Since the two printers work with different drivers, it seems to be a bit complicated. Any direct solution to this main issue?

To resolve the issue, I am trying to make this work with Ghostscript for the B printer. But I need an interface between ghostscript and the generic text/only driver. I have read information about the txtwrite device and the mswinpr2 device. With txtwrite, I can only extract the information and create a .txt document (how do I print the output?).

-sDEVICE=txtwrite -o -dSAFER -sOutputFile="C:\Users\myname\Documents\testfolder\test%%03d.txt" -

With mswinpr2, I can only print the raw data with all the unnecessary formatting script (can I add a filter?).

-sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -o -dSAFER -sOutputFile="%printer%PrinterB" -

How can I print a job using Ghostscript and a Generic/Text Only driver? With Ghostscript command lines or any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just found out. This is the ghostscript command lines. I am using Redmon19 to print the stdout.
-sDEVICE=txtwrite
-o -dSAFER
-sOutputFile=%stdout -

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lco1B.png)